# Am I specifying color-interpolation correctly in my SVG gradients?

Tags: svg, gradient, color-space

I want to interpolate linearly in an SVG gradient.  I guess that setting `color-interpolation="linearRGB"` is the way to do that.  But this seems to have no effect in any of the several browsers I've tried.  Both these stripes look the same to me, and a paint program's color picker isn't showing me any difference either:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grado" color-interpolation="sRGB">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00f" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lino" color-interpolation="linearRGB">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00f" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="90" fill="url(#grado)" stroke-width="0" />
  <rect x="0" y="95" width="1000" height="90" fill="url(#lino)" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

I gather from my Google searches that `linearRGB` tends not to be perfectly supported by software.  But I also get the impression (from some sources) that at least some browsers at least partly implement it.  So I expect to see a difference between the stripes in SOME browser.  Is there really no popular browser that supports this useful and trivially implemented operation, or am I just specifying the image incorrectly somehow?

Comment: Browsers don't support different color interpolations. If you want to adjust the interpolation, you have to use an SVG filter to adjust the color space.

Comment: This is something that is emerging as part of CSS level 4 color. But I am not aware of browsers implementing it as yet. Also, linear is great for compositing, but usually not what you want for gradients. I explain in this article: https://www.myndex.com/WEB/Gradients   (xyY is the linear plot)

Comment: Firefox now supports it in nightlies, should be in version 123. The gradients do look different but implementation was not trivial, we fake the linear gradient by creating a large number of intermediate colour stops to force the transition to be linear.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation, it seems that no browser support it yet. If Mozilla put a `?` in Firefox, it is really unknown.

In any case, what do you expect, as difference?

You case should show minimal effect: you are mostly changing the hue. In any case, I tried with `#000` to `#fff` on several browsers, and I still see no difference. In that case, the midgray should be at 0.5 in case of `sRGB` and at 0.18 in case of `linearRGB`.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox version 123 now supports color-interpolation="linearRGB" for gradients. If you run the snippet in the question you will see the cases are now displayed differently. Chrome is [also planning to support linearRGB](https://issues.chromium.org/savedsearches/6695506)